# How to make button using same root but different file in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a chess set on the computer. I've already finished the chess board, clock and name. To play chess you need pieces. So that's what I'm doing right now. I want the chess piece on the same root but on a different file to minimize the number of lines of code in one module. So I imported it like this:

```
from ScreenDisplay import Screen
```

I accessed the root like this and it worked well when I run it. I could see the board, the clock and the names.

```
self.Screen = Screen()
self.root = self.Screen.root
```

I tried adding a button on this file but it didn't show up.

```
self.Character = Button(self.root, image = self.Picture)
self.Character.grid(self.root, row = y, column = x)
```

(By the way, self.Picture, y and x are parameters of __ init __).
How can I make widgets appear on the screen while on a different module? Thanks!

Here is my entire code:
ScreenDisplay.py:

```
"Impport time module to create clock"
import time

"Import tkinter widgets"
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import Image

"Impport PIL to open images"
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


"Create chess board and timer"
class Screen:
    def __init__(self):
        "Create root"
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Chess")
        self.root.geometry("1400x700")

        "Resizing the image"
        self.Board = Image.open("ChessBoard.png")
        self.resizing = self.Board.resize((700, 700))
        self.ChessBoard = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resizing)

        "Putting the image in a label then putting it on the screen"
        self.ChessBoardLabel = Label(self.root, image = self.ChessBoard)
        self.ChessBoardLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 8, columnspan = 8)

        "Creating the labels and time control"
        self.AI = Label(self.root, text = 'AI', font = "Helvetica 18 bold", width = 40)
        self.AI.grid(row = 0, column = 8, columnspan = 7)

        self.Human = Label(self.root, text = "Human", font = "Helvetica 18 bold", width = 40)
        self.Human.grid(row = 7, column = 8, columnspan = 7)

        "Create time clook for both players"
        self.CountdownClock = Label(self.root, font = "Helvetica 18 bold")
        self.CountdownClock.grid(row = 0, column = 8)

        self.CountdownClock2 = Label(self.root, font = "Helvetica 18 bold")
        self.CountdownClock2.grid(row = 7, column = 8)

        "Run functions to activate the clocks"
        self.set_timer()
        self.countdown(self.CountdownClock)

        self.set_timer()
        self.countdown(self.CountdownClock2)

        "Create the loop"
        self.root.mainloop()

    def set_timer(self):
        self.t = 600
        return self.t

    def countdown(self, label):
        if self.t > 0:
            self.convert(label)
            self.t = self.t - 1
            label.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown(label))

        else:
            label.config(text = "Timer Completed")

    def convert(self, item): 
        self.seconds = self.t % (24 * 3600) 
        self.seconds %= 3600
        self.minutes = self.t // 60
        self.seconds %= 60
        item.config(text = "%02d:%02d" % (self.minutes, self.seconds))      


if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = Screen()
```

ChessPiece.py:

```
"Import the button widget from tkinter"
from tkinter import Button

"Import the Screen class from ScreenDisplay to display the pieces on the same window"
from ScreenDisplay import Screen

class ChessPiece:
    def __init__(self, x, y, picture):
        "Initialize the window here from the other file"
        self.Screen = Screen()
        self.root = self.Screen.root

        "Initialize atributes that will be used through out the code"
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.Picture = picture
        self.Taken = False
        
        self.Character = Button(self.root, image = self.Picture)
        self.Character.grid(self.root, row = y, column = x)

        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    piece = ChessPiece(2, 7, "WhiteBishop.png")
```

Comment: Since you have called `self.root.mainloop()` inside `Screen.__init__()` function, so `self.Screen = Screen()` will block the application and statements after that line will not be executed until the window is destroyed.

Comment: So I should only run the loop in the ChessPiece file?

Comment: For your current design, yes.  But if `ChessPiece` will be used for different chess pieces, then no.

Comment: ChessPiece will only be used for ScreenDisplay.

Comment: What I mean is that you should have multiple chess pieces, for example one for white bishop, one for black bishop, etc.

Comment: oh. You can forget about it now. I fixed the problem(well my dad helped me a bit)